# Shortest implementation of Doaitse Swierstra's "Typing dynamic typing" in OCaml

Tags: haskell, ocaml

(I hope this question is not "opinion-based")

The implementation of [Typing dynamic typing](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Typing-dynamic-typing-Baars-Swierstra/09ee3459fea8385bf759f64c65fc81cbe032146a) from Doaitse Swierstra in Haskell is more or less 200 lines of code. Doing the same in OCaml seems to require a significantly larger amount. Hence the question : What is the shortest implementation of this timeless classic using OCaml ?

(Assuming utility libraries like [Higher](https://github.com/ocamllabs/higher)/[Higher_Kinded](https://github.com/janestreet/higher_kinded) or others)

Comment: Are you asking for an existing short OCaml solution or for someone to create a short OCaml solution? If the latter, I’d recommend the Code Golf Stack Exchange.

Comment: I imagine there are many (?) out there. I have an implementation in ... 501 lines, using  libraries :)). I did not know that site, thank you. it might be a better fit.

Comment: Maybe you should put a link to your implementatuon so that you could be told how to make it shorter

Comment: You could try this site https://discuss.ocaml.org/